# What is the Directory Docker on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, rosetta-stone

I just installed Snow Leopard on my Mac, and I got the following message after a reboot:

> To open Director Docker, you need to install Rosetta.
>   Would you like to install it now?

What is the `Directory Docker`? I don't remember installing that software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Hewlett Packard printer software.  You probably don't need it.

Comment: Unless I have an HP printer. Is it the driver or just some accompanying software?

Comment: You normally don't need the management software that comes bundled with printers.  If your printer does not work without installing it, look at the HP website for a driver.

Comment: Mac OS X includes its own support for HP printers, so you shouldn't need the HP software any more.  See: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01846935

Answer (score 0):

This [Apple knowledge-base article describes **Rosetta** and its use for **Universal Applications**](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1730).
macRumors forum thread on [do I still need Rosetta](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=773855)?

And, from [The basics you need to know about Snow Leopard](http://venturebeat.com/2009/08/27/apples-snow-leopard-may-stop-you-from-doing-your-job/)

> Snow Leopard does support applications that haven’t been
> upgraded to run on Intel CPUs,
> but you’ll have to install Apple’s Rosetta tool to run pre-Intel software on Intel hardware.
> Apple seems to have deliberately removed Rosetta from Snow Leopard to goad users into abandoning their older Macs.

This is causing [some](http://blogs.zdnet.com/Apple/?p=4776) [fuss](http://forums.mactalk.com.au/46/72330-install-microsoft-office-2008-snow-leopard-without-rosetta.html) in the Mac community.
Including this local discussion --
**Superuser**: [What is Rosetta and why doesn’t Snow Leopard include it by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/32084/what-is-rosetta-and-why-doesnt-snow-leopard-include-it-by-default)

From [Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard FAQ](http://www.macintouch.com/specialreports/snowleopard/slfaq.html),

> Do I have to have Intel or Universal Binary versions of all my software, or will my Mac OS X PowerPC-based software and Classic Mac OS software still run in Snow Leopard?
>
> Like Leopard, Snow Leopard includes Rosetta, which makes it possible to run Mac OS X software written for the PowerPC on an Intel Mac. (Rosetta is now an optional install in Snow Leopard.)
>
> As for Classic Mac OS software, you're mostly out of luck. The Classic Mode, found in Tiger and earlier versions of Mac OS X, disappeared in Leopard and has not returned in Snow Leopard. An emulator such as SheepSaver or Mini vMac would work, though it would be more work to set up than the (formerly) built-in Classic Mode.

Comment: Seems like you answer a different question here; OP did not ask what Rosetta is (and if he had, then this would be a dupe of the question you linked to).

Comment: @Jonik, I felt that with the SL release, the Rosetta question would keep arising repeatedly. By the time I noticed the other SU question, these links were already at hand. Tried to keep duplicate information out of this answer.