# Inventory of apps which require Rosetta

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, rosetta-stone

I don't ever intend to install Rosetta on my current MacBook Pro, but there are some older apps on this which migrated their way over from an older laptop.

Short of launching each app and clicking away the warning, is there an easy way to identify apps which would require Rosetta?

With such a list, I could either choose to delete them or take the time to find an update.

(Rosetta is OS X software for running old PowerPC-compiled apps on Intel Mac - [more info about rosetta in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/32084/what-is-rosetta-and-why-doesnt-snow-leopard-include-it-by-default))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's built-in System Profiler (`/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler`) does this for applications, extensions (`.kext`s), and frameworks. For example, click on the "Applications" item in the contents list on the left, then look at the "Kind" column. I usually click on the column header to sort by Kind.

For other executable binaries that aren't full apps, such as command-line tools, you might be able whip up a shell script that iterates over `$PATH` (or the whole filesystem) and calls `file` on everything, grepping for "ppc".

Comment: I'm accepting based on the System Profiler trick. I also whipped up a script similar to what you suggested and already ran that.

Answer (score 1):

Macintouch has a page listing [applications which require Rosetta](http://www.macintouch.com/imacintel/rosettacompat.html).

Full list below:

```
A Sharp
Addressix

ACD Systems International
Canvas

Adobe Systems
Creative Suite
Photoshop Elements 


AfterTen Software
WeatherManX
WeatherMenu

Allume Systems
Spring Cleaning 8
StuffIt Deluxe 10
StuffIt Expander 10
StuffIt Standard 10

Alsoft, Inc.
DiskWarrior

Ambrosia Software
Snapz Pro 2

American Power Conversion (APC)
PowerChute

Antono Group
C-Pen driver

AOL
AIM
AOL client

Apani Networks
Apani VPN Client

Apple Computer
AppleWorks
DVD Studio Pro
Final Cut Pro
Final Cut Express
Logic Pro/Express Motion
Soundtrack Pro

ArcSoft, Inc.
PhotoStudio X

Artwork Systems
ArtPro
Nexus

Aspyr Media
Space Colony
Tiger Woods PGA Golf 2003

AtLast Software
Sketchup

Aupperle Services
Astro IIDC
DFG/1394-1 Drivers

Autograph Systems
CallHelix
Bitcartel Software
iRecordMusic

Blizzard Entertainment
Starcraft
Warcraft III

Bombich Software
Carbon Copy Cloner

Canto
Cumulus 6.6 Workgroup Client

Cisco Systems
Cisco VPN Client

CMS Products
BounceBack Professional

ColorBurst Systems
ColorBurst RIP X-Photo
ColorBurst RIP X-Proof

Corel Corporation
Bryce 5 (but see Bryce 5.5 under DAZ)
Corel Rave
CorelDraw: (mixed reports)
Photo-Paint

Contour Design
ShuttlePRO
ShuttleXpress

Crossman Software
MacPOSX

CTM Development
PowerMail

Dantz (now EMC Insignia
Retrospect 6.1
Retrospect 6.1 client
Retrospect Express
Retrospect Server 6.1

DAZ Productions
Bryce 5.5

Digidesign
Pro Tools

Diwan Software Limited
Ready,Set,Go!

Dymo Corporation
Driver for LabelWriter 400 Turbo Driver for LabelWriter 330 Turbo

Elgato Systems
EyeTV 1.8.4
EyeTV 2

Ergonis Software
PopChar X

Escape
Escape Medical Viewer

Eskape Labs
MyTV
MyTV.PVR

Extensis, Inc.
Suitcase X1

Fast Rabbit Software
Dolce Ear Training
Dolce Music Flash Cards
FRS Clocks and Time
FRS Coloring Book
FRS Division Drills
FRS Fraction Master
FRS Money Math
FRS Talking Calculator
FRS Test Printing System
FRS Time Tracker Pro
LOWA ESL Memory Game
Master Math Word Problems
Master the Facts Multiplication
Math Flash
School Time Quizzer
Teacher's Favorite Hangman
US Government and Constitution Quizzer
FileMaker, Inc.
FileMaker Mobile 8
FileMaker Pro 8
FileMaker Pro 7
FileMaker Pro 6
FileMaker Server 8
FileMaker Server 8 Advanced
[

Final Draft, Inc.
Final Draft

Firaxis Games
Civilization 3

Freeverse Software
3D Bridge Deluxe
3D Crazy Eights
3D Euchre Deluxe
3D Hearts Deluxe
3D Pitch Deluxe
3D Spades Deluxe
Active Lancer
Airburst Extreme
Best of OMG : Vol.1
Big Bang Board Games
Burning Monkey Casino
Burning Monkey Mahjong 2
Burning Monkey Puzzle Lab
Burning Monkey Solitaire
Enigma
Kill Monty
ToySight Gold
WingNuts
X-Words Deluxe

Fujitsu
ScanSnap scanner software

Glass Bead Software
In/Out Board
SnapMail
SnapTalk

Glenn Anderson
Eudora Internet Mail Server

Griffin Technology
Radio Shark

IBM
Lotus Notes
Imagine That
Extend

Infinite Nexus
Compare Folders
DriveGauge

Intuit
QuickBooks 2006
Quicken
TurboTax

Kodak
Kodak Easyshare

Koingo Software
Alarm Clock Pro
Blaze
Contact Keeper
E-Mail Commander
File Geek
Font Pilot
Mac Pilot
Password Retriever
PTE
Slideshow Magic
Track Destroyer

LaCie
FastCoder software
SilverKeeper

LEGO Group
Digital Designer

Leister Productions
Reunion

Lime Wire LLC
LimeWire

Logitech
Logitech Control Center

LyX on Mac
LyX/Mac

MaBaSoft
World Clock Deluxe

MacMedia
PhoneAgent
PhoneDirector
PhoneManager

MacPlay
Bejeweled 2 Deluxe

Macromedia
Dreamweaver 8
Fireworks 8
Flash 8

Macsoft Games
Age of Empires 2 Gold Edition
Railroad Tycoon 3
Zoo Tycoon 2

MacSpeech, Inc.
iListen

MalcolmHardie Solutions Limited
SQLEditor

MathWorks
MATLAB

Maxtor
OneTouch Manager
Maxtor Quick Start

Metric Halo
Mobile I/O Console

Micromat
TechTool 4

Microsoft
Messenger 5
Office 2004
Office v.X
Remote Desktop Client for Mac
Virtual PC 7

Mozilla.org
Firefox
Thunderbird

Nemetschek North America
VectorWorks

NeoOffice.org
NeoOffice

Nikon, Inc.
NikonView

Norbert M. Doerner
CDFinder

Novell, Inc.
Groupwise 6.5 client

Now Software
Now Up-to-Date & Contact

Object Park Software
MenuCalendarClock for iCal

Onscreen Science
OnScreen Particle Physics

Open Text Corporation
FirstClass client

OTAG Technologies Ltd.
iSMARTtrain

Palm, Inc.
Palm Desktop

QSA ToolWorks
Helix Server
Helix Utility OS X
Update Collection OS X

Qualcomm
Eudora

RagTime GmbH
RagTime 5 & 6

Ranchero Software
NetNewsWire Lite

Recosoft
PDF2Office Professional

Red Rock Software
Deltagraph

RedleX
Mellel

Roxio
Popcorn
Toast 7

SAS
JMP

Sassafras Software
KeyAccess
KeyConfigure
KeyServer

Script Software
CopyPaste
CopyPaste Lite
Easy Card
iBeenFramed
ID Tunes
iClock
iKey
iSay
iStar Composer
iStar Karaoke
iWatermark
KnowledgeMiner
NetCheck
Project Timer Pro

Sean Kelly
skEdit

Skype Limited
Skype

Softpress Systems Limited
Freeway Express
Freeway Pro

Software MacKiev
Kid Pix Deluxe 3X
Dr. Seuss' ABC

SPSS, Inc.
SPSS 11

Steve Green
X-Chat Aqua

Symantec
Norton Anti-Virus 10

Techno Grafik
iTaskX

Telestream
Flip4Mac

Totally Hip, Inc.
LiveStage Pro

Trans-Tex Software
Tex-Edit

Transcena Design
OfficeTime

WebEx Communications
WebEx

Xochi Media Inc.
iScreensaver Designer
```

Comment: Nice list, but I'm looking for a tool/script which will analyze the software currently installed on *my* machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did before I found Spiff's response.

Wrote a simple script called `ppconly` to check for ppc executables. Contents:

```
#! /bin/bash

file "$1" | head -1 | grep "Mach-O executable ppc"
```

Then did this `find` command from within `/Applications`:

```
find . -type f -perm +111 -exec ppconly {} \; ; say "find rosetta completed";
```

(the `say` part at the end gave me an audio notification when it completed)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:

```
on open the_Droppings
    set dropped_Files to {}
    set dropped_Folders to {}
    set drop_List to ""

    set theFilePath to (path to desktop as string) & "dropped_files.csv" as string
    set theFileReference to open for access theFilePath with write permission

    repeat with a_Drop in the_Droppings
        tell application "Finder"
            set file_Name to the name of a_Drop
            set file_Kind to the kind of a_Drop
            write file_Name & "," & file_Kind & return to theFileReference
        end tell
    end repeat
    close access theFileReference
end open
```

**Kinds:**

- Application (Intel)     = Doesn't require Rosetta, only runs on Intel processors
- Application (Universal) = Doesn't require Rosetta
- Application (PowerPC)   = Requires Rosetta